# Print CSS URL on new line

Tags: css, printing, print-style

For print styles, I am currently printing the url after the text.
Is it possible to have it appear on the next line instead of next to the text?
This is what I have so far.

```
a:after {
  content:" (" attr(href) ")";
}
```

**Result:**

Email me(hello@email.com)

**Want this instead:**

Email me

(hello@email.com)

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qesRk/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
a:after {
    font-style: italic;
    content: "\A and some text after."; white-space:pre;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SZ3gg/)

Comment: @calebo: You didn't use the code Dipaks suggested: http://jsfiddle.net/qesRk/1/ Or are you saying it works on screen but not print?

Answer (score 1):

You could `display: block;` it, like on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tdk66/)

Comment: doesn't work for print style, if i add display: block to the pseudo class :after, it doesn't get picked up.

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to make the `:after` pseudo-element start on a new line, as shown in other answers. But the example in your question says that the desired rendering is

Email me

(hello@email.com)

This cannot be achieved using just CSS if the the purpose is to that the address from the `href` attribute of a link. The reason is that a working `href` value would have to start with `mailto:`, and you cannot omit anything from the attribute value when using constructs like `attr(href)`. What you can achieve is

Email me

(mailto:hello@email.com)

For this, given the markup `<a href="mailto:hello@email.com">Email me</a>`, you would use

```
a:after {
        content: " (" attr(href) ")";
        display: block;
        margin-top: 1.2em;
}
```

assuming that you want an empty line too, as in your example. Replace 1.2 by the line-height value you are using.

P.S. This sounds unnecessarily complicated anyway. Using just the email address in content, optionally wrapped inside an `a href` element, would suffice, both on screen and on print. (On printing, you would normally want to suppress underlining of links, but that’s a general issue.) If you were thinking of preventing email address harvesters from getting the address from the content, putting the address into an attribute does not help much (they are easily processed by harvesters).